# Setting average as baseline rather than a dummy variable in a glm

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution

I have binomial data (meaning k successes out of n trials) for a set of conditions.

I would like to fit a `glm` in order to quantify the effect of each condition on the success. Since the data are overdisperesed I thought of using a negative binomial `glm` (`glm.nb` from the `R` `MASS` package does that).

Code snippet (though not really overdisperesed):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(k = as.integer(runif(200,1,20)),
                 n = as.integer(runif(200,100,200)),
                 cond = rep(LETTERS[1:20],10),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
df$cond <- as.factor(df$cond)
library(MASS)
fit <- glm.nb(k ~ cond + offset(n), data = df)
```

Obviously `cond` A will be set as baseline and all effects will be relative to it. However, this makes interpretation very difficult for me. Therefore my question is how do I fit a `glm.nb` model where the effects are relative to the mean across all conditions rather than the dummy variable set as baseline?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the intercept you get an estimate for each level. If you then subtract out the mean from k you should get estimates relative to zero (the overall mean). You may need to remove the offset from the formula and specify offset = ..., not sure. Try both ways if necessary.

Comment: Thanks mdewey. Can you please provide the code for your answer? It's not clear to me what you mean by subtracting the mean from k as k both depends on its respective n as well on the condition. Thanks!

Comment: I had read mean but not remembered that you are modelling a count so only the first part of my answer works.